# Prisma: using `none` to filter

Tags: prisma

I am trying to get a list of users that meet all of the following criterias

1. users who have at least one `Hired` position record
2. in these `Hired` position records, users should have at least one `CONFIRMED` applicant in the future.

I am using prisma Composite type filters `none`, but it's not working.

Even though there are users who have `Hired` position record but don't have future `Confimred` work, this query returns nothing to me.

```
await prisma.user.findMany({
  where:{
    position:{
      some:{
        stage: "Hired",
        applicant:{
          none:{
            status: "Confirmed",
            work:{
              start_date:{
                gt: new Date()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks for your help in advance!